# sql query in netbeans

Tags: sql, netbeans

I am trying to execute the following query but I got no response. The SQL is saying there's error with `?` tags.
Can anyone can help please?

```
select basket_id shopping_basket 
WHERE cust_id
(INSERT INTO order (cust_id, basket_id, total, order_status) values ('?', '?', '?', '?'))
```

Comment: Your SQL statement is invalid. You're selecting from an `INSERT` statement. What are you trying to do within your block of code?

Comment: Can you please specify what do you want to achieve? Execute two queries one after another or what?

Comment: Boris am trying to select cust_id from local variables and insert it into order table

Comment: @shawn, am trying to get cust_id from local variables and insert it into order table

Comment: now i changed my query to ....INSERT into `order`(cust_id,basket_id) VALUES ('?','?'),
(SELECT cust_id, basket_id from shopping_basket where cust_id = (SELECT MAX(cust_id) FROM `shopping_basket`)) .                   but still doesnt work

Comment: "Local variables" as in something inside your application? You are trying to `INSERT` some specific fields into your `order` table. Are these values passed through a form?

Comment: If you want to `INSERT` based on a `SELECT`, the syntax would be like `INSERT INTO order (cust_id, basket_id, total, order_status) SELECT cust_id = xxxx, basket_id, total = (calculation for total), order_status = (calculation for order_status)....`. You wouldn't need the `?` placeholders or a `VALUES` declaration on the `INSERT` because the `SELECT.....` takes place of the `VALUES`. You'll still want to watch for SQL Injection, though.

Comment: @Shawn thanks but it doesn't, i get errors like NULL EXCEPTION with the following prepareStatement try {
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(qry);
            while(res.next()){
              Shopping_Basket.basketId=res.getInt("basket_id");
               Login.CustomerId = res.getInt("cust_id");
            }
            pst2.setInt(1, Login.CustomerId);
            pst2.setInt(2, Shopping_Basket.basketId);      
            res = pst.executeQuery();

Comment: @user11150643 You'll need to provide a lot more of your code context. Edit your question. I'm not sure what SQL you are sending to your database, but above typed SQL isn't a valid insert statement.